# Vue - v-if query not as expected

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

i am still learning with vue.. and actually i got a problem to show a div only when updated_at not the same like created_at

```
v-if="news_data.updated_at != news_data.created_at"
```

i have already searched some sites regarding v-if and the operant ones, but always only queries with equality.

How can I query that my DIV is displayed only if the two values are not identical ?

Comment: That is the syntax. If you want to make sure they are identical use `!==` instead of `!=`. If it's not working, log the two in the console, because this syntax should work as intended.

Comment: The mistake was that I tried to compare the two values directly in the v-for. This did not work... Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the type of `news_data.updated_at` ?